# What happens to entries when the month changes?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am on the free plan. I am testing and considering signing up for a better plan if tests are successful.

What happens to entries when the month ticks over? Do they get deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not!  The [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) Individual plan is just that, a full-featured plan for individuals, not a time-limited trial.

Organizations on the Individual plan can create up to 500 new entries per month.  Entries above this limit will be locked, but nothing will be deleted and your form will always continue to accept new submissions.  This limit applies to the number of new entries each month, not the total number of entries.